# What is the context or the scope of the top level of the *.js file of Node.js or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Javascript file of Node.js, expressions written at the toplevel of the file are evaluated as they are, unlike Java and other languages.

What should I call this? : global level, top level, module level, or global context.

P.S. Please excuse my poor English. 
Thanks.

Comment: Within node top-most context would be `global.` in browser it will be `window.`

Comment: Thank you, Rikin. It sound good. It may be better to call "global context" on Node.